# MYSQLI Insert data from html table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using JS that is doing some calculations and date forecast based on data already being pulled and display the calculation results into an HTML table.

How can I then with e.g. a click of a button -  copy that data from the HTML and insert it into a table in my database using `php` and `mysqli`?

```js
function forecastClient() {

    const bankHolidays = new Set([
        Date.parse("April, 19 2019"),
        Date.parse("April, 22 2019"),
        Date.parse("May, 6 2019"),
        Date.parse("May, 27 2019"),
        Date.parse("August, 26 2019"),
        Date.parse("December, 25 2019"),
        Date.parse("December, 26 2019"),
        Date.parse("January, 1 2020"),
    ]);

    function addWorkingDays(date, days) {
        function workingDay(date) {
            while (true) {
                let day = (date.getDay() + 1) % 7;
                if (day < 2) date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2 - day);
                if (!bankHolidays.has(date.getTime())) break;
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            }
        }
        workingDay(date);
        while (days--) {
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            workingDay(date);
        }
        return date;
    }

    const dateStr = document.querySelector("#startdate").value.replace(/-/g, "/");
    const date = new Date(dateStr);
    addWorkingDays(date, 0); // Make sure it is a working day
    const td = document.querySelectorAll("#forecast td.date-forecast");
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        td[i * 2].textContent = date.toDateString();
        td[i * 2 + 1].textContent = addWorkingDays(date, 27).toDateString();
        addWorkingDays(date, 1);
    }
};

function myfunction() {
    event.preventDefault();
    doForecast(0);
}

function doForecast(index) {
    var nextIndex = index + 1;
    var startBalance = null;
    var additionalAmount = (document.getElementById("additionalAmount").value != '') ? parseFloat(document.getElementById("additionalAmount").value) : null;
    var additionalMonth = parseFloat(document.getElementById("additionalMonth").value);
  
    var additionalAmount2 = (document.getElementById("additionalAmount2").value != '') ? parseFloat(document.getElementById("additionalAmount2").value) : null;
    var additionalMonth2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("additionalMonth2").value);
  
    var additionalAmount3 = (document.getElementById("additionalAmount3").value != '') ? parseFloat(document.getElementById("additionalAmount3").value) : null;
    var additionalMonth3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("additionalMonth3").value);
  
    if (index == 0) {
        startBalance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("startBalance" + index).value);
        if( additionalMonth == 1 && additionalAmount != undefined){
          startBalance += additionalAmount;
        }
        if( additionalMonth2 == 1 && additionalAmount2 != undefined){
          startBalance += additionalAmount2;
        }
        if( additionalMonth3 == 1 && additionalAmount3 != undefined){
          startBalance += additionalAmount3;
        }
    } else {
        startBalance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount" + index).innerHTML);
        if( additionalMonth > 1 && additionalMonth == (index + 1) && additionalAmount != undefined){
          startBalance += additionalAmount;
        }
        if( additionalMonth2 > 1 && additionalMonth2 == (index + 1) && additionalAmount2 != undefined){
          startBalance += additionalAmount2;
        }
        if( additionalMonth3 > 1 && additionalMonth3 == (index + 1) && additionalAmount3 != undefined){
          startBalance += additionalAmount3;
        }
    }

    var interestRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("interestRate").value);
    var fee = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fee").value);
    parseFloat(document.getElementById("interestRate").value);
    var vat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("vat").value);

    interestRate = interestRate / 100;
    fee = fee / 100;
    vat = vat / 100;

    var simpleInt = startBalance * interestRate;
    var profitfee = simpleInt * fee;
    var afterVAT = profitfee * vat;
    var amount = (startBalance + simpleInt - profitfee - afterVAT).toFixed(2)

    var stringIndex = "" + (nextIndex);
    document.getElementById("startBalance" + stringIndex).innerHTML = startBalance.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("simpleInt" + stringIndex).innerHTML = simpleInt.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("profitfee" + stringIndex).innerHTML = profitfee.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("afterVAT" + stringIndex).innerHTML = afterVAT.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("amount" + stringIndex).innerHTML = amount;
    if (nextIndex < 12) {
        doForecast(nextIndex);
    }
}

function start() {
    forecastClient();
    myfunction();
}
```

```html
<body onload="start();">

  <div class="form-group col-mb-3">
    <label onkeyup="" for="forecastLive">Live Date: <input value="03/27/2019" id="startdate"></label>

    <label for="startBalance">Start Balance
     <input id="startBalance0" value="1000">  
  </label>
    <input type="hidden" onkeyup="myfunction()" id="interestRate" value="20" />

    <input type="hidden" onkeyup="myfunction()" id="fee" value="30" />

    <input type="hidden" onkeyup="myfunction()" id="vat" value="20" />
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="form-group col-mb-3">
    <label for="additionalAmount">Aditional Amount
<input onkeyup="myfunction()"  id="additionalAmount" value=""></label>
    <label for="Month">Month
<input onkeyup="myfunction()"  id="additionalMonth" value="">
</label>
    <br >
    <label for="additionalAmount2">Aditional Amount
<input onkeyup="myfunction()"  id="additionalAmount2" value=""></label>
    <label for="Month">Month
<input onkeyup="myfunction()"  id="additionalMonth2" value="">
</label>
    <br >
    <label for="additionalAmount3">Aditional Amount
<input onkeyup="myfunction()"  id="additionalAmount3" value=""></label>
    <label for="Month">Month
<input onkeyup="myfunction()"  id="additionalMonth3" value="">
</label>

    <br>
    <br>

    <style>
      .forecast table,
      .forecast tr,
      .forecast td,
      .forecast th {
        border: 1px solid;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
    </style>

    <table class="forecast table table-striped" id="forecast" onload="myfunction()">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Month</th>
        <th scope="col">Month Start</th>
        <th scope="col">Investment</th>
        <th scope="col">Return</th>
        <th scope="col">Fee</th>
        <th scope="col">Vat</th>
        <th scope="col">Closing Balance</th>
        <th scope="col">Month End</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>

        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance1"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt1"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee1"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT1"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount1"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance2"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt2"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee2"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT2"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount2"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance3"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt3"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee3"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT3"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount3"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance4"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt4"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee4"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT4"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount4"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance5"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt5"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee5"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT5"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount5"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance6"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt6"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee6"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT6"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount6"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance7"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt7"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee7"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT7"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount7"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance8"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt8"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee8"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT8"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount8"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance9"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt9"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee9"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT9"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount9"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance10"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt10"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee10"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT10"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount10"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance11"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt11"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee11"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT11"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount11"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance12"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt12"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee12"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT12"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount12"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: phpmyadmin _is not_ a database. It's just a bunch of php scripts that makes you _access_ a database.

Comment: Where are you trying to insert any data into any database? I can't even find anything that sends a request to a php script!? So it's unclear what the problem/question is!

Comment: I'm asking how I would do it? I have used forms before with $_POST but how do I insert all the data from my HTML table to my database table... mariaDB

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is 4-10 tasks in one question.... First make an ajax call to a php script with the data beeing sent (and received/understood), then verify the data, then send it to database, then verify it's beeing updated, ... For now the question is far too broad, since nothing from the described tasks is somehow implemented. What would you expect from an answer here? To provide you the full code (without knowing what your backend looks like, what the db structure is, etc...)?

Comment: @Jeff - No. I expect some suggestions or a rough explanation on how It can be achieved. I think my question is simple, How can I insert data from a HMTL table using php - the table in the database is the same as how you see it in HTML, same column names etc

Comment: Here's again the rough explanation: _"First make an ajax call to a php script with the data beeing sent (and received/understood), then verify the data, then send it to database, then verify it's beeing updated"_

Comment: @Jeff is there any links I can read up on - in particular - some documentation that gives some form of guidance or introduction to what I am wanting to achieve... I have never used Ajax

Comment: You can find 1000 Ajax tutorials with a simple Google search, you don't need us to type into Google on your behalf

Comment: Another approach if you don't want to use Ajax is to make everything you want to submit into a form field (either hidden or text box or whatever), and just use a normal postback

Answer (score 1):

To call a PHP script from your JS code, you need to use AJAX. On your button click fetch the values you want to insert to your table and send the data to your php script using ajax. Below I have given a simple code to send 4 values to the php script. If you want to send more data you can specify them on `data` field of `ajax`.

```
$(#yourButtonID).click(function(){      
    var start_balance = $(#startBalance0).val();
    var interestRate = $(#interestRate).val();
    var fee = $(#fee).val();
    var vat = $(#vat).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{s_balance:start_balance, i_rate:interestRate, fee:fee, vat:vat}
        success: function(data){
            alert('success');
        }
    });
});
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
    $s_balance = $_POST('s_balance');
    $i_rate = $_POST('i_rate');
    $fee = $_POST('fee');
    $vat = $_POST('vat');
    // perform your insertion and echo result you want
?>
```

Comment: I tired your code, and no data was inserted into the table

Comment: @GeorgeRichardson you sure your insert query working fine?